# MariaDB 10.3 gap of numbering of the sequence

Tags: mariadb, sequence, database-replication, mariadb-10.3

I have a table where id is primary key and squence.
In transaction I call sequence

```sql
select NEXTVAL(next_cons_id) as next_cons_id
```

then create a new record where field id = next_cons_id got from code bellow.

DDL sequence

```
CREATE SEQUENCE IF NOT EXISTS next_cons_id START WITH 1;
```

In most cases it work well. 
Having done a small study I found some patterns.

```
Id, ... gap ..., nextId
606401,605557,
604556,605401,
603555,604401,
602594,603401,
601594,602401
```

Ids with dates:

```
601594  2019-10-10 00:04:54
602401  2019-10-10 01:36:33
602594  2019-10-10 21:46:43
603401  2019-10-11 01:19:49
603555  2019-10-11 21:41:26
604401  2019-10-12 00:30:09
604556  2019-10-13 00:15:32
605401  2019-10-13 03:51:42
605557  2019-10-13 22:42:22
606401  2019-10-14 02:14:28
```

And after I did create console script that make insert by one record per second in test table:

```
237343  2019-10-14 00:31:03 2019-10-14 00:31:03
237344  2019-10-14 00:31:03 2019-10-14 00:31:03
....gap...
238000  2019-10-14 00:31:04 2019-10-14 00:31:04
```

It table use only test script.

But it time we can see some problem:
[image]

There were no network problems at this point
[image]

In monitoring of zabbix rollback of transactions not found.

Database has one replication server.

Server version: 10.3.13

Do you have any ideas to fix this?

UPD: 
I remove the sequence and recreate this table with 
`id primary key autouncrement` but this case has been repeated.

Comment: By default, `CACHE` is set to 1000.

Comment: Thnx, I can't test it. See the UPD above.

Comment: Is the Question about gaps?  About slowdowns?  About resource usage?  Something else?  If it is about gaps, I cannot tell from your examples which number(s) are missing.

Comment: Were there any `ROLLBACKs`?

Comment: @rick-james Yes, you are right. This problem was in cache of sequence.  Thank you!